# Show and hide layout on scroll coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using coordinator layout with collapsing toolbar. Please help to achieve the desired look. 
I am trying the toolbar to be visible when scrolled up else toolbar should not shown.

**I want the page should look as**

**Default view as**

[image: Default view]

**When scrolled up**

[image: When scrolled up]

I get the toolbar visible on default view and gets hide when scroll to top.

These are my xml files.
**Activity Layout is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Activity.ProfileActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePhoto"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_photo_placeholder_male"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <include layout="@layout/collapse_toolbar_home"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_profile" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_pencil_white_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Toolbar layout is:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/src" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/result" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/time_table" />

</LinearLayout>
```